# Matrix multiplication in ROS CPP

Tags: c++

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,
I would like to write a node that reads data from a file, a vector and a matrix, and as part of the task this node is supposed to preform I need to multiply the vector by the matrix. Is there already a data structure in ROS library that one can use to create vectors and matrices. If so, How does the matrix multiplication is carried out?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/62328/matrix-multiplication-in-ros-cpp/) by [Solmaz](https://answers.ros.org/users/2778/solmaz/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2013-05-07

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The recommended linear math library to use is [Eigen](http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/)

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2013-05-07

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 4